# parallel computing toolbox fminsearch

Tags: matlab

I have never used parallel computing before. Thats why my question can be silly. I have a optimisation program for my least squared function "bla"

```
d=@(p)bla(m1,m2,m3,p,m2,m3);
pstart=0.2;
[pbest,likemodelvalue]=fminsearch(d,pstart,options)
```

But it is extremely slow. Can I use prallel programming with fminseach, for each value of "p"?

Comment: Maybe you can try with distributing the domain among different matlab workers. Then the global min will be the min among the distributed results.

Answer (score 2):

The Optimization Toolbox has some parallel computing facilities, for which you also need to purchase Parallel Computing Toolbox. These capabilities are described here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/using-parallel-computing-with-fmincon-fgoalattain-and-fminimax.html . I'm not sure if that's quite what you want though. If you want to find multiple different values of `pbset` for different values of `pstart`, you could do something like this (again, using Parallel Computing Toolbox)

```
matlabpool open local % launch local workers
pstart = 0:0.2:10;
for ii = 1:numel(pstart)
    [pbest(ii), likemodelvalue(ii)] = fminsearch(d, pstart(ii), options);
end
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I want to find the "p", which minimizes my matrix. And fminsearch tries to do it by many values of "p", starting with "pstart". Is it possible, that matlab looks for this "p" values not one after another but rather simultaneously?